# Word to describe something of something of something

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, french

What is a word for recursion/nesting of an entity in English ? I'm looking for a word that replaces the colloquially used [-ception](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:-ception) suffix. A generic term that encapsulates all nested attributes. For instance:

word - abbr is the *abbreviation of abbreviation*
image - (Droste effect) a wall with a hanging picture of *the wall with the hanging picture*
Eg: [Ummagumma album art](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81-Joj09kIL._SL1300_.jpg) , [Droste Cacao](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Droste.jpg)
math - (recursion) function of *a function* Eg: f(f(x))
object - two mirrors placed facing each other
abstract - dream within *a dream*

Preferably a word or a phrase, but any other way to convey the same is also welcome. The French seem to have covered all the expressions out there. However, I'm looking for the English counterpart of what the French call **mise en abyme**.

Comment: *Fractals* have a property known as *self-similarity*; Hofstadter famously explored such recursive ideas in Godel, Escher, Bach, and gave a name to a certain, special class of such tangled hierarchies: the *strange loop*.

Comment: Please do not invoke the Sith Lords: nobrv8!

Comment: Would English have borrowed the term [*mise en abyme*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mise%20en%20abyme) if we already had a good word for it?

Comment: I don't think "mise en abyme" covers all your examples. They don't all cover an infinite loop.

Comment: Please use full words. 'sth' can mean many things as well as 'something'.

Comment: @ermanen Neither does recursion. A recursion terminates when the base case is reached. This website is named based on the error you get from an infinite recursion.

Comment: *Recursion* covers *infinite recursion* also. So it covers both your finite and infinite examples.

Comment: Already gave a +1 tho

Comment: @ermanen: *mise en abyme* does not require infinite loops, at least in French.

Comment: @PeterShor: It seems like French and English Wikipedia definitions are a bit different. But all the examples I could find about "mise en abyme" are about infinity and even its name refers to this. But anyway, it seems like it still doesn't cover all the examples and recursion is an all-encompassing term.

Comment: @ermanen: If you can't find any non-infinite examples, you either haven't been looking very hard, or have been looking in the wrong language. [The French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme) gives the play within the play in *Hamlet,* and the nested stories in *1001 Nights* as examples of *mise en abyme*. And the name ***does not*** refer to infinite recursion. The French Wikipedia explains that it refers to heraldry, where the recursion depth is two (a shield within a shield, although there are much better pictures of this elsewhere on the web).

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes I was looking in English, I didn't look deeper, you are right :) Thanks for the details. I didn't mean where the name comes from, its meaning refers to infinity: "placed into abyss"

Comment: @ermanen: While *abyme* may mean *abyss* in French in general, the specific meaning here was the middle of the shield (technically called *l'abyme* in French heraldic jargon for reasons I don't understand). And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme#Heraldry) is a picture of a shield within a shield within a shield, apparently an actual heraldic shield.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks, didn't know that and the article says: "One could imagine another shield in its center and so on, forever and ever into the abyss.."

Comment: @ermanen - There's no such thing as an "infinite loop".

Comment: @HotLick: There is. But I think it is more of a programming term :)

Comment: @ermanen - Is there any evidence you can point to to show that an infinite loop has ever occurred?

Comment: @HotLicks: You can easily find if you search. (as a term). I'm not sure where you are getting at though but I won't be involved in your infinite loop any further:)

Comment: @HotLicks 10 PRINT "An infinite loop is occurring." 20 GOTO 10

Comment: @Mazura - And how is that actually infinite?

Comment: @HotLicks It was a joke. [Infinity does not exist.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710291/does-an-equation-containing-infinity-not-equal-0-or-infinity-exist)

Answer (score 2):

The term is **infinite regress**.

> An infinite regress in a series of propositions arises if the truth of proposition P1 requires the support of proposition P2, the truth of proposition P2 requires the support of proposition P3, ...
>
> Infinite regress in optics is the formation of an infinite series of receding images created in two parallel facing mirrors.
>
> Infinite regress in consciousness is the formation of an infinite series of "inner observers" as we ask the question of who is observing the output of the neural correlates of consciousness in the study of subjective consciousness.
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

**Notes**

1. The expression *infinite regress* has a wider application than *recursion.*  This is because recursion has an implication of traversing a procedure. Infinite regress can happen naturally without human intervention or even human existence.
2. In the case of a dream within a dream, the regression will presumably not be infinite - in that case I think **nesting** is a perfectly good answer. This allows for a finite number of, possibly different, dreams within a dream.

Comment: It doesn't have to be infinite but there is infinite recursion also. And "recursion" has a wider application. It covers all his examples.

Comment: @ermanen - Thanks for your comment (I didn't down-vote you by the way) I would say that recursion implies self-similarity. If I dream that I dream that I dream that I wake up, then okay. However I might dream that I can fly and in that dream have a dream that I can walk on water. That would be nesting rather than recursion.

Comment: Yes but it is not the question. You are talking about a different concept in your example. And for the downvote no worries, this is the hour of my fans.

Comment: This is interesting

Answer (score 1):

It *is* called ***recursion***.

> Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way. For instance, when the surfaces of two mirrors are exactly parallel with each other, the nested images that occur are a form of infinite recursion.
>
> The term has a variety of meanings specific to a variety of disciplines ranging from linguistics to logic. The most common application of recursion is in mathematics and computer science, in which it refers to a method of defining functions in which the function being defined is applied within its own definition. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

*Recursion* doesn't only apply to maths and it covers all your examples.

Comment: If 'recursion' _is_ the answer, surely it's general reference, as OP mentions it and should have checked in Wikipedia..

Comment: I wasn't aware of the linguistic use of recursion. Back when I was learning recursion, Wikipedia had only the article on computing.

Answer (score 0):

A colloquial term that is used for the kind of nesting described is the familiar **matryoshka doll** (A doll within a doll within a doll, etc.). From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll#As_metaphor) article:

> Matryoshkas are used metaphorically, as a design paradigm, known as the "matryoshka principle" or "nested doll principle". It denotes a recognizable relationship of "object-within-similar-object" that appears in the design of many other natural and crafted objects.